# multiple authentication validation is not working

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.8

i have two guards "customer" & "adminuser". In the admin login login page, validation rules are not working in logincontroller. i have checkRole middleware for admin user. why is this not working. is authentication is done by that checkRole middleware? same issue with customer login. can access adminhome(admin dashboard page) without entering any login details. how is that happen? how can i solve this.

here are my routes

```
`Auth::routes();
 Route::get('/index', 'FrontController@index')->name('index');
 Route::get('/admin/login', 'adminloginController@ShowAdminLoginForm')->name('adminLogin'); 

 //Customer Register Route
 Route::post('/register', 'FrontController@storeRegister');

 //Login Routes-Post Data
 Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest:customer'], function () {
 Route::post('/customerLogin', 'Auth\LoginController@customerLogin'); 
 });

 Route::group(['middleware' => 'roles:adminuser'], function () {
 Route::post('/adminUserLogin', 'Auth\LoginController@AdminLogin'); 
 });

 Route::view('/adminhome', 'home');
 Route::view('/customerhome', 'index'); 

 Route::get('/adminlogout', 'Auth\LoginController@adminlogout');
 Route::get('/customerlogout', 'Auth\LoginController@customerlogout');`
```

here is logincontroller.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Login Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
| redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
| to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
|
*/
use AuthenticatesUsers;
/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
//protected $redirectTo = '/home';
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    $this->middleware('roles')->except('logout');
}

/**
 * Admin Login
 */
public function AdminLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username'   => 'required|min:3',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|max:6'
    ]);
    $status = Auth::guard('adminuser')->attempt([
        'email' => $request->username, 
        'password' => $request->password,
    ]);
    if ($status) {
        //dd($status);
        return redirect()->intended('/adminhome');
        //return redirect()->intended('/adminhome');
        //$request->session()->flash('success', 'Login Successfully!');
        // return redirect('/adminhome'); // redirect to admin dashboard
    }
    //$request->session()->flash('error', 'Sorry,Login Unuccessfull!');
    return redirect()->back();
    //return back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
}

/*public function getUserId()
{
    $admin_user_id = Auth::guard($guard)->user()->id;
    return $admin_user_id;
}*/

//login for the customer
public function customerLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required|min:3',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|max:6'
    ]);

    $status = Auth::guard('customer')->attempt([
        'email' => $request->username, 
        'password' => $request->password], 
        $request->get('remember'));
    //dd($status);
    if ($status) {
        return redirect()->intended('/customerhome');
        //$request->session()->flash('success', 'Login Successfully!');
        //return redirect()->intended('/index');
    }
    //$request->session()->flash('error', 'Sorry,Login Unuccessfull!');
    return redirect()->intended('/customerhome');
    //return back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
}

/*public function getUserid()
{   
    $id = Auth::guard($guard)->user()->id;
    return $id;
}*/

public function adminlogout(Request $request)
{   
    //$request->
    Auth::guard('adminuser')->logout();
    //$request->
    session()->flush();
    return redirect('/admin/login');
}

public function customerlogout(Request $request)
{   
    Auth::guard('customer')->logout();
    return redirect('/index');   
  }
}
```

checkrole Middleware,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\AdminUser;

class CheckRole
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{   
    if ($guard === "adminuser" && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/adminhome');
    }
    if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/admin/login');
    }
    return $next($request);
  }
}
```

Built in RedirectifAuthenticated Middleware for customer login,

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{       
    //dd($guard);
    if ($guard === "customer" && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/customerhome');
    }
    if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/index');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

}

Comment: Validation errors are stored in the sessions. Do check your sessions first

Comment: thanks for responding. i'm new to laravel, how can i check that?